# Highcharts tooltip custom CSS turning the caret/arrow white

Tags: css, highcharts

I have applied some custom CSS styling to my Highcharts tooltip that better aligns with my current design, but there's two minor issues with my styling:

1. The caret/arrow is a white color
2. The white border outline does not show up on the caret/arrow and instead strikes through the arrow

This is the CSS I used:

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 300px;
  pointer-events: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

P.S. the chart is intentionally squished to 100 px is to test tooltip transparency onto the value labels

I'm not quite sure how to change the color of the arrow back to black since I am using the `background-color` tag which I am assuming only applies to the color of the rectangle.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mznaybs/83/

Comment: Is that the desired result?: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/778hLso8/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that what you looking for :
The arrow is a svg path so you must apply a fill color in it.

```
.highcharts-tooltip path{
  fill:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

*The white border outline does not show up on the caret/arrow and instead strikes through the arrow* 
According to your js code there isn't any border but you added a `box-shadow`

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
  ...
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);*/
  ...
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mznaybs/88/)